# Is there a more elegant way to pass Parameters to Invoke-Command?

Tags: powershell

I have a function that will be executed in an internal network, but through WINRM on a server in DMZ.

Basically all the functionality will be inside `Invoke-Command`. The thing is, I'll have about 10 Parameters.

Is there a more elegant way to pass parameters to `invoke-command` instead of listing them 3 times?

```
function foo {

    Param(
        $a,
        $b,
        $c,
        $d,
        $e,
        $f
    )

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName bar -ScriptBlock { 
        Param(
            $a,
            $b,
            $c,
            $d,
            $e,
            $f
        )
        <#Stuff#> 
    } -ArgumentList $a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass `$PSBoundParameters`

```
function foo {
    Param(
        $a,
        $b
    )
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
        param(
            $z
        )
        Write-Output $z["a"]
        Write-Output $z["b"]
    } -ArgumentList $PSBoundParameters
}

Foo -a "TEST Number 1" -b "TEST Number 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

The other alternatives are the $using: scope, or referring to $args[0], $args[1], etc.